# Jenkins MultiConfig Project is not importing python modules correctly

Tags: python, git, jenkins, git-submodules

I have a python project being tested using Jenkins multiconfig.
When checking out the project, Jenkins creates a folder with the job name and within it, a folder called branch which contains a copy of the git repo for each brand (this is the value that changes for each configuration)

There is a submodule on the git repo, and it is correctly checked out on the folders under brand, but not in the main folder.

Now when the job runs, it fails because those modules  being are not found but they are in there.

I'm assuming that the modules are being looked up in the parent folder instead of in the folders under brand.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before, and if so can point me in the right  direction so I can import those modules that *are* there?

Many thanks